# HTML Template Django counter for buttons

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates, django-views

I have to panels one with the current data and one to update.
I need a smart way to update the number for tab5 and tab6 for each element. Without repeating any of the numbers. 
The Tab only works if the 2 Numbers are only there.
I tried calculating inside the template with |add but that works only once not in a loop. Maybe some javascript could help?

For a better example: element1 = tab5 tab6, element2 = tab7, tab8, element3 = tab9, tab10

Anyone got a good idea ?

VIEW:

```
locationdata = LocationData.objects.values_list(
    'name',
    'street',
    'plz',
    'tel',  
    'website',
    'description',
    )


context = {
        "locationdata" : locationdata, 

        }
```

Template:

`{% for item in locationdata %}`

```
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">

{{item.0}}
{{item.1}}
{{item.2}}
{{item.3}}

<li role="presentation"><a href="#tab6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">

input field = update item.1 and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the id provided by djangos model and changed tab5 to tab{{id}} and tab6 to tabs{{id}} ;) not pretty but it is working